# Unpacking Multiple ViewData Results

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

So I want to display results from multiple queries from the same controller.

I have a controller method like this in mind:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
            string tmp_username = Membership.GetUser().ToString();
            ViewData["lemons"] = lemondb.lemon.Where(p => p.user == tmp_username).ToList();
            ViewData["sugar" ] = lemondb.sugar.Where( p => p.user == tmp_username ).ToList();
            return View();
}
```

And a view that resembles this:

```
    @foreach (var action in (List)ViewData["lemons"]) {
...
            @Html.DisplayFor( action.amount )
...
            @Html.DisplayFor( action.acidity )
    @foreach (var action in (List)ViewData["sugar"]) {
...
            @Html.DisplayFor( action.amount )
...
            @Html.DisplayFor( action.sweetness)
```

But I get an error on the 'foreach' lines that says something like:

> CS0305: Using the generic type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   requires 1 type arguments

What argument am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a simple C# issue. You should cast the object from the ViewData to `List<T>`, where you have to replace `T` with the element type of your list. Check the type of the lemondb.lemon property to find out your element type.

If the type is `LemonTrader.Models.Message` then try:

```
@foreach (var action in (List<LemonTrader.Models.Message>)ViewData["lemons"])
```

Comment: tried "@foreach (var action in (List)ViewData["lemons"] as List<LemonTrader.Models.Message>) { ... " Got the same error.

Comment: I think moving the cast out of the "as" to parens that precede the ViewData call helped. Unfortunately, the "@HtmlDisplayFor( action.acidity )" now has this problem: "The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." Shouldn't I be able to call "action" like it is an object of type LemonTrader.Models.Message?

Comment: Your suggestion for the @foreach statement definitely worked, but for some reason I can't get anything out of the "action" object. When I tried: "<%= action.msg %>" it literally translated this to "<%= action.msg %>".

Comment: When I went with "@Html.DisplayFor( (LemonTrader.Models.Lemon)action.acidity)" said it couldn't convert string to LemonTrader.Models.Lemon. When I cast it as (string)action.acidity, it says, "The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: It seems like if action.msg is a string, it should be able to display it . . .